# Git перенос коммитов с одной ветки на другую

Tags: git

Создал ветку, сделал пару коммитов, а потом понял, что забыл переключиться на новую ветку, подскажите пожалуйста как можно перенести эти изменения на новую ветку и как откатить старую ветку